# Making a Makefile of two executables in c++

Tags: c++, makefile

I have two main program called walk.cpp and useWalker.cpp which use the class I implemented. I have the class file Walker.h and Walker.cpp, and I am required to make a Makefile which contains the target walk, the target useWalker and a target all.
This is how my Makefile look like:

```
all:
    walk useWalker

//comment:sorry to delete the rest parts because it is a homework problem and I do not want my solution to be public. I will only keep the mistaken part.
```

And when I try to enter the command "make", there is an error message:
walk useWalker
make: walk: Command not found
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127

I don't know what mistake I made in my code to generate this error message and how to fix it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line should read:

```
all: walk useWalk
```

Makefile language is sensitive to whitespace, and "all:" followed by a new line, a tab and "walk useWalk" means "target all depends on nothing, execute the command 'walk useWalk' to make it".

Answer (score 1):

```
all:
walk useWalker
```

should be

```
all: walk useWalker
```

What you're doing now is asking make to run `walk useWalker` when you ask it to `make all`.

Comment: That's a new question, totally unrelated. Ask it as a new question